# knockout.js binding error within foreach block

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js and am having a problem with binding within a **foreach** section.  I am receiving the error:

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: hideSearchElements is not defined;
Bindings value: click: hideSearchElements

Here is an exert of the html:

```
 <div id="searchResults" data-bind="visible: searchIsVisible">
  <label id = "lblSearchResults">select a template:</label>   
  <div data-bind="foreach: titles">
    <div data-bind="text: Title"></div>
    <div data-bind="click: hideSearchElements">hide</div>
 </div>
```

And an exert from the viewModel:

```
var viewModel = function () {      
    this.searchIsVisible = ko.observable(true);               

    this.showSearchElements = function () {
       this.searchIsVisible(true);
    };

    this.hideSearchElements = function (
       this.searchIsVisible(false);                    }
    }

 return new viewModel();
```

I have both **showSearchElements** and **hideSearchElements** working fine outside of the foreach block but when inside it, I get the error.

If I add `$parent.hideSearchElements` I can bind but then get an error saying:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'searchIsVisible' 
.

I have probably have two distinct issues but thought the detail may help :)

I'm keen to understand what's going on here?  Can anyone help please?

A link to the relevant page in the documentation would also be very helpful - I'm reading through that now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was right when use `$parent.hideSearchElements` because `hideSearchElements` function is in a parent context. You got exception because when `knockout` calls your function `this` has another context. You have to use closure to store `this` pointer. Update your view model as follow:

```
var viewModel = function () {   
    var self = this;   
    self.searchIsVisible = ko.observable(true);               

    self.showSearchElements = function () {
       self.searchIsVisible(true);
    };

    self.hideSearchElements = function (
       self.searchIsVisible(false);                    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just this second figured that out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904070/knockoutjs-click-binding-within-foreach-binding.